# PostgreSQL Ltree to JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, ltree

I've been experimenting with PostgreSQL's Ltree extension. I'd like to use it to store hierarchical to-do list data (i.e. lists with sub lists). It works well, but after spending a fair bit of time, I still can't find a nice way to retrieve the information from the database in hierarchical JSON format. Here is an example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
 id |        content         | position | parent_id | parent_path 
----+------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------+
  1 | Fix lecture notes.     |        1 |           | root
  2 | Sort out red folder.   |        1 |         1 | root.1
  3 | Order files.           |        1 |         2 | root.1.2
  4 | Label topics.          |        2 |         2 | root.1.2
  5 | Sort out blue folder.  |        2 |         1 | root.1
  6 | Look for jobs.         |        2 |           | root
```

From this, to the json output below:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "content":"Fix lecture notes.",
      "position":1,
      "parent_id":null,
      "parent_path":"root",
      "children":[
         {
            "id":2,
            "content":"Sort out red folder.",
            "position":1,
            "parent_id":1,
            "parent_path":"root.1",
            "children":[
               {
                  "id":3,
                  "content":"Order files.",
                  "position":1,
                  "parent_id":2,
                  "parent_path":"root.1.2",
                  "children":[]
               },
               {
                  "id":4,
                  "content":"Label topics.",
                  "position":2,
                  "parent_id":2,
                  "parent_path":"root.1.2",
                  "children":[]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "content":"Sort out blue folder.",
            "position":2,
            "parent_id":1,
            "parent_path":"root.1",
            "children":[]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":1,
      "content":"Look for jobs.",
      "position":1,
      "parent_id":null,
      "parent_path":"root",
      "children":[]
   }
]
```

Is there any neat way this can be done, maybe with Python server side? Looking for ideas really!